# OpenCV project 3D coordinates to 2d camera coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera

I have the 3D-world coordinates of an object and I want to get its coordinates in the camera-2D-plane.
I have already calibrated the camera using `cv::calibrateCamera`, so that I have the **camera matrix** and **distortionCoeffs**.

For projecting the 3D-point to 2d-camera-coordinates, I use `cv::projectPoints`. [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints) says:

> void projectPoints(InputArray **objectPoints**, InputArray **rvec**,
>   InputArray **tvec**, InputArray **cameraMatrix**, InputArray **distCoeffs**,
>   OutputArray **imagePoints**, OutputArray **jacobian=noArray()**, double
>   **aspectRatio=0** )

*How do I get rvec/ tvec and is my approach right?*`calibrateCamera`gives me `rvecs` and `tvecs`, but they are for each input chessboard-image and I guess, they are the rotation and translation of the chessboard and not of the camera.

Comment: Well, they describe the rotation and translation of the camera relative to the chess board. If you know the rotation and translation of the chessboard relative to your world coordinate system you can easily compute the extrinsics of your camera in the world coordinate system.

Comment: But why do I need this translation/ rotation matrices? Should it work with only the camera (=projection?) matrix?

Comment: The camera matrix only contains the [intrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters) parameters like focal length and not the [extrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Extrinsic_parameters) parameters which are the rotation and translation of the camera.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. In the projection matrix p, there are both (intrinsic and extrinsic) parameters, aren't there? So theoretically, I would just have to multiply  p with the homogeneous 3D-coordinates in order to get the 2D-homogeneous coordinates of my point, right? Is there a OpenCV function for this?

Comment: If you have such a matrix you don't need a function to do this. Just multiply your point with the matrix and divide the result by its third entry. Of course this does not take distortion into account. But for this to work you need the a transformation from your world coordinate system to your camera coordinate system. And you stated so for you only have transformations to the checker boards.

Comment: moving camera or moving chessboard ist equal (inverse). choose any one of the calibration values. Your choice does only influence the coordinate system!

Comment: @sietschie each checker board defines one 3D world coordinate system

Comment: @Micka yes, but he needs to use the same coordinate system he measured his 3D points in.

Comment: @sietschie I multiplied now the projection matrix and the R3 coordinates, but I do not get the exact 2D coordinates. Opened new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966759/opencv-stereo-vision-3d-coordinates-to-2d-camera-plane-projection-different-than/36983258#36983258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have the **projection matrix** (`P`), I can calculate the 2D coordinates (`x`) in the camera plane like this from the 3D-coordinates `X` (using **homogeneous coordinates**):

> x (u,v,w) = P * X (x1,x2,x3,w)

I just have a *problem with the rectification*, so that I do not get the exact projection to my 2d image. See here: [OpenCV stereo vision 3D coordinates to 2D camera-plane projection different than triangulating 2D points to 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966759/opencv-stereo-vision-3d-coordinates-to-2d-camera-plane-projection-different-than)